# how to define a form select-name containing an individual id

Tags: php, forms, post

this is a part of my code in a form (where aid is a single number):

```
echo "<select name='update-status".$q['aid']."'>";
```

how can i define $stat as $_POST['*select-name*']?

so it would look like this:

```
$stat = $_POST['update-status2'];
```

i tried this without luck obviosly:

```
$stat = $_POST['update-status".$q['aid']."'];
```

Comment: `$fieldName = "update-status" . $q['aid']; $stat = $_POST[$fieldName];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the extra `'"` at the end.

```
$stat = $_POST['update-status' . $q['aid']];
```